# Playing sound though http server iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, avplayer

Hi I want to play a mp3 file via my server e.g. http://test.com/hi.mp3

At the moment the code plays the file if its in the directory of the code.
The code also enables only 1 sound at a time.

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];   


}
```

However this code here enables me to play the sound through the http server, but I can play multiple sounds at once, I need the sound in sessions so only 1 sound can play at once. I have 10 sounds.

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {

    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/hi.mp3"]] retain];

    [player play];

}
```

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer.  I think you are saying that you need the player to work so that only one sound can play at once, but you should define what you want to happen - should sounds queue up to play one after another, should the second sound be ignored and not play at all if started when another sound is currently playing?

Comment: I want to create sessions with the 2nd piece of code, because the sounds are playing simultaneously which I do not want. I want the sounds to play separate. So once u tap a sound it plays, and once you tap another sound, the previous sound stops and the other begins. Using the http mp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to move the pointer for your player from being declared in that method so that it is declared at a module level (in the .h file) - either just defined in the interface, or defined as a @property.  Then you can access this player in another method later.

Then when you wish to switch to a new sound in another method you could try:

```
[player pause];    // stop the player from playing
[player release];  // free the reference count
// start a new plaer
player = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/nextsound.mp3"]] retain];
```

You should be careful with the 'retain' call here.  The playerWithURL will be passing back an autoreleased object, so depending on what you are doing elsewhere with autorelease pools, and depending on whether you are using a property including (retain) in its definition, you may not need to call retain here.